# HTACCESS: Redirect VS RedirectMatch to redirect one page to another on same domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have my HTACCESS file here (below), and I want to redirect /payments to /design/payments just to make it a little easier when sending the link to clients.

Here is the whole file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 http://mrobertsdesign.ca/404

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mrobertsonline\.ca [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mrobertsonline\.ca [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mrobertsdesign\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mrobertsdesign.ca/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

The file works fine, if you see anything that should be changed, please let me know as well. But it works fine, any ways...

To redirect the page "/payments" to "/design/payments", I understand I should use "redirect" as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /payments /design/payments
```

But when I add that, it redirects me to:

```
http://mrobertsdesign.ca/design/payments?page=payments
```

Now I don't understand what exactly I need to change, that's all really, all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a blocking condition before your rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

She gets fired with a request to `/payments`, adds the parameter and then the `Redirect` keeps those added parameters.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/payments
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

As a side note may be you also want to add the `[QSA][1]` flag in the last 3 rules, because when you add parameters in a RewriteRule, the previous query string gets lost.